# How to know the trained model by AutoML?

Tags: google-cloud-automl

I used AutoML Vision to train a model to predict cancer based on images. It works quite well. I want to know what the model is, whether it is CNN, how many layers.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

We don't normally release the exact details of the model because we want to, and continue to, change it under the hood as newer better models come out.

It is a relatively deep CNN.

Comment: I see. Thanks a lot!